# Karma runner: how to load plugin from file (inlined plugins)

Tags: karma-runner

I want to add a plugin from a local file to Karma. I found this example in the documentation (version 0.1):

Documentation to karma runner

```
// inlined plugins
  {'framework:xyz', ['factory', factoryFn]},
  require('./plugin-required-from-config')
```

This is not even valid javascript. When I try the `require` version of registering I get

> Plugin is not registered.

The require version the same.

How is this supposed to be?

Comment: Latest doc says *{ 'framework:karma-json-fixtures': ['factory', require('../tools/karma-json-fixtures')]}*. But that gives me _Can not load, it is not registered!_

Comment: I came across this problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not so hard.
First of all you should add your plugin to 'plugins' property in karma.config.js after that you could us it.

```
module.exports = (config) => {
   config.set({
     frameworks: ['xyz'],
     plugins: [
       'karma-*',
       {
         'framework:xyz': ['factory', ()=> console.log('Your code')]
       }
     ]
   })
}
```